# I-macron without space

Tags: symbols, characters

I want to write the name Ibn-Sīnā with macrons over the i and the a. I found out that can I add macrons using `\=a` and that I need `\=i\` to avoid the dot over the i.

When I write `Ibn-S\=i\n\=a` I get an error, undefined control sequence. If I put a space after the i (`Ibn-S\=i\ n\=a`) it works, but I don't want a space after the i.

I also tried `Ibn-S\=\in\=a` but that also generated an error.

How can I do it?

Comment: I've been trying to search for solution and found many similar questions, but not how to deal with this problem. Excuse me if it's been up before.

Comment: You can type `S\={\i}n\=a` (the braces are optional around the `a`.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I need to be better at using {}.

Comment: @Tbbe As [David points out in his answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245836/9077), your mistake was to use ``\=i\`` to get a macron over a dotless `i`. The correct command is `\=\i` or `\={\i}`. The question is then really about how to write `ī`, and that is covered by the dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not `\=i\`  but `\=\i` `\i` is the dotless i command.

If you use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

then you should just be able to  type  Ibn-Sīnā  directly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012B}{\=\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0101}{\=a}
\begin{document}

[ Ibn-Sīnā ]

or

[ Ibn-S\={\i}n\={a} ]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! but if I try Ibn-S\=\in\=a, but now I get ! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> $

Comment: @Tbbe you have used `\in` which is the math command for set inclusion, as always you need to separate tex commands from following letters so `\={\i}n` or if you want to omit the `{}` then `=\i n`

Comment: the input `[ Ibn-S\=\i n\={a} ]` is correct too -- that's with an ordinary space after `\i` (same as previous comment by david; remember: a space following a command ends the command, but is then ignored).  using the space doesn't disable inter-letter kerning, which the braces might.  in this case it doesn't much matter, but some other letters are much more affected by kerning with the adjacent letters.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\=\i{}` would inhibit kerning as that's an empty group but `\={\i}` (which is the official syntax, which always uses braces) does not as there the `{}` are macro argument delimiters so vanish as the argument is parsed.

Comment: That rendered correct too.